# Get links to stay active

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hyperlink, highlight

I have 4 options that, when clicked, the clicked option becomes focused and its background-color/text color change, while all the other revert to the normal states. I have some code where I can change font color, but I can't figure out how to change the div color. I'm also trying to figure out in CSS and with this code how to have one of the options be by default highlighted when the page loads.

Jquery- the last line "($("a")" is the line of code that changes font color; the code above it has to do with a filtering system I have on the page.

```
$(function () {
         var $panels = $( '#image-wrapper .panel' );

        $( '#category > div > a' ).on( 'click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var categoryToShow = $( this ).data( 'filter' );
            $panels.addClass( 'active' ).filter( '.' + categoryToShow ).removeClass( 'active' );
            $("a").addClass("active-color").not(this).removeClass("active-color");
            /*$("#category .current-div").addClass("active-bg").not(this).removeClass("active-bg");*/
        } );
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="category">
            <div class="all-div current-div">
                <a href="#" data-filter="all"><h2>ALL</h2></a>
            </div>
            <div class="ed-div current-div">
                <a href="#" data-filter="ed"><h2>EDITORIAL</h2></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pr-div current-div">
                <a href="#" data-filter="pr"><h2>PR</h2></a>
            </div>
            <div class="cr-div current-div">
                <a href="#" data-filter="cr"><h2>CREATIVE</h2></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#content, 
#category {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#category div {
    float: left;
    margin: 40px 0 0 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 240px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#category .all-div {
    background-color: #000000;
}
#category .all-div a {
    color: #ffffff;   
}

.active-color {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: green;
}
.active-bg {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: how about using the this.parent() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, .on was not working on your selector so i changed it to .live and changed your selector for the backgrounds to .current-div because your a tags need display: block to have a visible background.

check this:

http://jsfiddle.net/A3n7S/15/

```
$(function () {

     var $panels = $( '#image-wrapper .panel' );

     $(".current-div").not('.all-div').first().addClass("active-color")
     $( '#category > div > a' ).live( 'click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();  
        var categoryToShow = $( this ).data( 'filter' );
        $panels.addClass( 'active' ).filter( '.' + categoryToShow ).removeClass( 'active' );
        $(".current-div").not('.all-div').removeClass("active-color");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active-color");

      /*$("#category .current-div").addClass("active-bg").not(this).removeClass("active-bg");*/
    } );
});
```

Replace that:

```
.active-color {
   color: #000000;
   background-color: green;
}
```

with:

```
 #category .active-color {
   color: #000000;
   background-color: green;
 }
```

Comment: okay i changed the code to reflect a vision of mine about what you want to have as result

Comment: Yeah that's the idea, except I'm trying to have the black div revert to gray once a new link is clicked (so it resembles the other 3 non-active links); that is just the default starting position. I just did that in CSS because I wasn't sure how to do it.

Comment: Okay, fiddling with your code I figured out how to get it to do what I want. Thanks a bunch. The only thing I need now is to figure out how to have one of the divs start out focused already.

Comment: Yes! I figured out everything except "$(".current-div").removeClass('all-div active-color');" Awesome. Very much appreciated.

Comment: Another quick question- I have images that go transparent when one of the filters is clicked, any reason why it doesn't work in IE7/8?

Comment: You, sir, are a God amongst men. Thank you.